# How can I convert fstring to str.format?

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

```
HEADER_LENGTH = 10
my_username = input("Username: ")
username = my_username.encode()
username_header = f"{len(username):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}"
```

How can I 'username_header' be changed from fstring to str.format()?
I must run on python3.5. so I can't use fstring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must work:

```
username_header = '{0:<{1}}'.format(len(username),HEADER_LENGTH)
```

you can use keyword args also

```
 username_header = '{user_len:<{header_len}}'.format(user_len=len(username),header_len=HEADER_LENGTH)
```